# Destructuring JavaScript returns an error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a function and I am trying to destructure couple params from options

```
  fetchArtifactsWithFiltersOG = async options => {
   
    const { nextPage, fromSearch } = options;

  }
```

**Issue:**

However, there are some use cases where `options are not passed`, in which case it throws a `nextPage of undefined error`.

How do I destructure in this case where I am not sure if options is only passed sometimes. Without making my syntax ES5.

Comment: why don't you assign them default value ?
like const { nextPage = null, fromSearch } = options; 
then you can do like if( nextpage ) { do someting.....} else { do something else }

Comment: ^ What if options is null? when it throws an error indefinitely which is what I was referring to in my post. @parseshyam

Answer (score 5):

Set a default value for the options argument.

```
async (options = {}) =>
```

or

```
async (options = { nextPage: 1, frontSearch: false }) =>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add default values:

```
const { nextPage, fromSearch } = options || { nextPage:null, fromSearch:null };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a default value to options:

```
fetchArtifactsWithFiltersOG = async (options: {}) => {

    const { nextPage, fromSearch } = options;

}
```

or

```
fetchArtifactsWithFiltersOG = async options => {

    const { nextPage, fromSearch } = options || {};

}
```